# "Assistance Order" is an acceptable use in the context of furniture business?

Tags: vocabulary

I work at a company that makes software used in furniture designing, manufacturing and selling. It is used by designers, factories and stores. We are building a feature where i.e.:

- A store received a broken piece that is part of the design and they want the factory to send this specific piece again;
- A factory can request a new adjustment to the designer because there were some differences in the materials;

In a nutshell, it indicates that something needs to be done, and the user can select a specific section of the design that needs this "something". It is similar to a Technical Assistance but not exactly.

All of this is done opening a new [thing that we're trying to name]. The first name thought were "Assistance Order", but it sounded odd to some of us. So we tried thinking a little more, and then "Assistance Request", "Help Request", "Ask for help" were other suggestions.

Are any of these suggestions applicable to the meaning we're trying to convey? Is there a better way to call this?

Comment: This might be a better fit for another SE site ([UX?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/)  I've never visited that site).  All these phrases might, in the right context, convey the intended meaning, but they're all vague enough that they also might suggest something different to certain users.

Comment: All your ideas centre around "help" or "assistance".  But your examples are not about asking for help.  The store with the broken piece doesn't want "help", they want a replacement. I think you'll have to rethink this.  Investigate similar products, but you;ll know better than me which products have similar features.

Comment: Replacement request is what I would use: Help/replacement request. "assistance order" does not work at all. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider the term "Special Assist", reflecting the fact that these occurrences are unusual, rare. Or perhaps "Special Request". I don't think anyone would like "Special Plea", do you?

Comment: special plea is a legal term, in anything.